# fcolorbox not wrapping text

Tags: color, paragraphs, box

I'm trying to get an `fcolorbox` to wrap my text according to the standard paragraph width. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \fcolorbox
            {black}
            {gray!20}
            {\lipsum[2-4]}
    \end{center}
       
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it won't wrap. I've tried using `\parbox` inside `\framebox` and vice versa, but neither seems to work.

How do I get my `fcolorbox` to adequately wrap the text?

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong `\parbox` syntax. `\parbox` takes two arguments, namely the width of the box and its content. I was omitting the width.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \fcolorbox
            {black}
            {gray!20}
            {\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[2-4]}}
    \end{center}
       
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that with `\textwidth`, you'll have an \fcolorbow overflowing into the margin.

Comment: I'd rather it didn't overflow into the margin. What's the difference between `\textwidth` and `\linewidth`?

Comment: This depends on the context. With the code you posted there's no difference. But I tried with `0.98\textwidth`and there was no overflowing (tested with `showframe`).

Comment: Try `\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\lipsum[2-4]}`,  or if you like `\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\lipsum[2-4]}`- `\fcolorbox` width will be exactly `\textwidth`.